# What is the plural of “stiffness”?

Tags: grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

I’m proofreading for a friend (not that I am an expert on English or his subject matter!), and he has used the word *stiffnesss* in an engineering context.

I believed the plural should be *stiffnesses*, but a quick Internet search suggests that *stiffness* might be a noun without a plural, such as *sheep* or *furniture*.

Excerpted examples:

> connected to its neighbour by spring and bending stiffness’s
>
> these stiffness’s and the damping encountered are calculated by

Comment: Maybe it should be "[degrees of stiffness](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3343634)" rather than "stiffnesses", although I agree with you that between _stiffness's_ and _stiffnesses_, only the latter is possible. Can you give us the sentence?

Comment: Stiffness can have a plural if you are talking of a variety of materials which have different stiffnesses. [Hm. Firefox has squiggled that as a misspelling. But then it doesn't like "Firefox" either.] Anyway, it was OK when I was an engineering undergraduate.

Comment: Different materials may have different values for their stiffness parameter or different degrees of stiffness but they can not have "stiffnesses". In this case, the principle of euphony should prevail (even in engineering).

Comment: Could I ask why this got a down-vote, and how I might improve the question to correct it?

Comment: 'Sheep' is count; 1 sheep (singular form) and 17 sheep (plural form). 'It does not have a plural' is incorrect. The singular noun has an invariant plural [form]. //// 'Furniture', though almost always used as a non-count usage, has been countified (in a sense different to the original meaning of 'furnitures'. See [You Can Master English
By Mathew Adukanayil](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FejMuZSR3ksC&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=%22different+furnitures%22&source=bl&ots=ftwAn-H7hs&sig=ACfU3U2_3QtnG3B7e1vVn4Ky1TLXix4SBQ&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22different%20furnitures%22&f=false) (p91)

Comment: though 'collective nouns' should be 'nouns usually found in non-count usages'.  'The word _furnitures_ would [apply to] different _styles_ of furniture, such as Indian, Chinese, Western ...'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *-ness* suffix is an extremely productive one in English, with thousands of resulting words being attested by the dictionary and more being coined daily as need or whim arises.

Although it is typically used to turn adjectives and participles into abstract nouns expressing a state or condition, like *hardness* or *willingness*, it can even be roped into service by pronouns and adverbs, as in *me-ness* or *everydayness*.

In general, the resulting state or condition is considered a mass noun not a count noun.  Words like *kindness*, *happiness*, *openness*, *darkness*, and *madness* do not normally lend themselves to inflected plurals like *kindnesses*, *happinesses*, *opennesses*, *darknesses*, and *madnesses*.

However, like other mass nouns, these can become plurals when you are discussing separate instances of that thing, such as the *darkness* of a moonless night being distinct from the *darkness* of a shuttered room, and those therefore being two different *darknesses*, or even simply speaking of small *acts of kindness* as *kindnesses*.

Moreover, some common words ending in *-ness* have more readily passed into count-noun territory, including such words as *illnesses* and *businesses*. This is more easily done once the word is no longer apprehended as having been a base adjective to which a substantive-producing suffix has been applied.

So while you would be in unassailable territory using a construction like “different degrees of stiffness”, writing “different stiffnesses” can certainly make sense in the right context.

---

PS: Words like *witness* and *wilderness*, and of course *lioness* and *villainness*, have their own stories.  The first pair gained their *-ness* long ago and have no base words to which we can now reduce them, while the second pair are actually the feminizing *-ess* suffix applied to a word that already ends in *-n*.

Comment: So in conclusion, 'maybe' is the answer ;) I'll pass on this feedback to the author, thank you very much.